# Solve for $k$ the following equation

Tags: calculus

I need to find the value of $k$ for which the following holds.

$$2^{\frac k2 + 1} = 3^k + 1$$

and $k\in\mathbb{R}$.

But I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Isn't 0 an obvious answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $k=0$ the equation holds.

Now define
$$f(x)=3^x-2^{\frac x2+1}+1$$

Then
$$f'(x)=3^x\ln 3-\frac12 2^{\frac x2+1}\ln 2=3^x\ln 3- (\sqrt 2)^x\ln 2$$

But
$$\frac{3^x\ln3}{(\sqrt 2)^x\ln 2}=\left(\frac 3{\sqrt 2}\right)^x\log_23$$
So $f'$ is positive for some interval $(c,\infty)$ and negative for $(-\infty,c)$.

We see also that $c<0$ because $f'(0)=\ln 3-\ln 2>0$.

Namely, 
$$c=\log_{3/\sqrt 2}\log_32\approx -0.612$$

To see if there is a solution in $(-\infty,c)$, we compute
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=1-1+1=1$$
so we see that $f(x)>0$ at some interval $(-\infty, k)$ and $f(-1)=\frac43-\sqrt 2<0$, so, by Bolzano's theorem, there is another solution.

There are no more solutions because $f'$ vanishes only at one point.

Comment: Good answer. But we could also use the fact that both functions are continuous and then apply the intermediate value theorem to $2^{\frac{-1}{2} +1}>3^{-1}+1$ and $2^{\frac{-2}{2} +1}<3^{-2}+1$, so that there is a solution between $-2$ and $-1$? This seems easier and more intuitive.

Comment: I prefer, when possible, making an analysys before just trying values. May be unpractical.

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov But that way doesn't prove that there aren't other solutions than the two found.

Comment: I agree, but I was more thinking about the topic starter and the fact that the problem seems elementary, maybe pre-calculus?

Comment: @ploosu2 that's true, that makes this a better answer indeed

Answer (score 1):

Since solving does not seem to be easy, you might look what happens for simple values. It turns out that $$2^{\frac02+1}=2^1=3^0+1=1+1.$$
The graph below, however, suggests there is another solution. It's approximately $-1.484$ but I don't really see how to get there manually either. Plus, I have this Symbolab application in which I tried to plug in this equation, but even with that I don't get a nice solution.

If you're asked for *the* value of $k$, I think the question is just wrong since there are two solutions.

[image: This graph]

Answer (score 0):

There are two (real) solutions: $x=0$ and $x\approx -1.48378$.

This can be seen by studying the function $f(x) = 2^{x/2+1}- 3^x-1$. Its derivative is $f'(x) = 2^{x/2} \log(2) - 3^x \log(3)$ which has one root

$$x_0= -2\frac{ \log(\log 2 ) - \log(\log 3)}{\log(2) - 2 \log 3} \approx -0.6124.$$

By checking at some value on each side we notice that $f'(x) > 0$, when $x<x_0$ and $f'(x)<0$ when $x>x_0$ (by continuity of $f'$).

Hence $f$ has a local maximum at $x_0$ and is strictly monotonic on each side. By checking, we see that $f(x_0)>0$ and also that $f(x_1)<0$ for some $x_1 < x_0$ and similarly that $f(x_2)<0$ for some $x_2 > x_0$ (take for example $x_1=-2$ and $x_2 = 1$). By continuity, $f$ has exactly $2$ roots.

As is easily notices, the second solution (on the right side of $x_0$) is $0$. The first solution can be approximated, but I don't know if one can get a nice algebraic expression for it.